# Will this code get the value of the found control? asp.net syntax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, findcontrol

```
x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areasexpertise1", FindControl("AreasExpertise1"))
```

It should find AreasExpertise1 and make a parameter, but does that get the selectedvalue too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will find the control and will return it as a `Control` object.

You need to cast it to whatever control it is (DropDownList or RadioButtonList, or whatever it is you are using), and then call the `SelectedValue` property on it in order to do so:

```
var ctrl = FindControl("AreasExpertise1") as DropDownList;
if (ctrl != null)
  x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areasexpertise1", ctrl.SelectedValue)
```